# How to get the width and height of an Image View in android?

Tags: android, imageview

In my code I have an `Image View` in my XML layout and I keep changing the source image for this in my code. Now I want to know the width and height of the generated image each time.

I tried using `getWidth()`, `getHeight(),` `getMeasuredWidth(),` and  `getMeasuredHeight()`, but they all return 0.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Where you calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on ImageView? If you calling from `onCreate()` in activity, it won't work. You need to wait for activity window to attached and then call `getWidth() and getHeight()` on ImageView. You can try calling `getWidth() and getHeight()` from `onWindowFocusChanged()` method of your activity.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    int width=imageView.getWidth();
    int height=imageView.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: that returns zero the very first time that the image is loaded, and then the correct size every time after that..

Comment: How does one do this in a fragment?

Comment: onWindowFocusChanged just work on API18 and over, and it can't be best way... however thanks

Comment: I have set the imageview height and width to 300dp in xml but when i run your method i get the output as 450dp for height and width. Please Help

Answer (score 14):

try this

```
 ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
 ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
           finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
           finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
           Log.e("hilength","Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this code works too, but I guess the solution provided by Veer will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

if you set ImageView a drawable, and the ImageView's height and width type is WRAP_CONTENT, you can get the ImageView's height and width by this even you calling from `onCreate()`

```
int height = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
int width = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
```

Comment: This seems useless if you get the image from url.

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
int finalHeight, finalWidth;
final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size_label);
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
        finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
        tv.setText("Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
        return true;
    }
});
```

it's really working...

Answer (score 1):

The way you make **reference to the image object** is wrong. That's why you are given zero all the time. first create a bitmap object from imageview and get the width and height from it.

When taken a image from cam I do the following and it works like a charm.

```
Bitmap image2 = (Bitmap) data1.getExtras().get("data");
double width = Double.valueOf(image2.getWidth());
Log.v("WIDTH", String.valueOf(width));
double height = Double.valueOf(image2.getHeight());
Log.v("height", String.valueOf(height));
```

Hope it helps for you.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert the image to mutablebitmap and the try to get the width and height of the image and mostly this will solve your issue..

```
    Bitmap Rbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap).copy(
                    Config.ARGB_4444, true);

Rbitmap.getWidth();
Rbitmap.getheight();
```

Comment: The question is how to get height and width of the image view not a bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getBackground()).getBitmap();
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
```