# set Bitmap as size of image View

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-bitmap

i'have Get Bitmap from oneActivity to secondSctivity in imageview. Now i want this bitmap as the same size of Imageview. but this code is now working.

```
    ViewTreeObserver vto = ph.getViewTreeObserver(); 
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            ph.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this); 
            ph.getMeasuredWidth();
            ph.getMeasuredHeight(); 
            return true;
            } 
        });


    // set contact Photo Bitmap in Image view-------------------------------------------------

    byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
    if (byteArray != null) {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    }

    if (bmp != null) {
        Bitmap bmpimg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,ph.getMeasuredWidth(),ph.getMeasuredHeight() , true);
        ph.setImageBitmap(createRoundedBitmap(bmpimg,5));



    } else {
        ph.setImageResource(R.drawable.upload_photo);
    }
```

what i have to do for that???

Comment: First you find your Imageview width and height then scaled your bitmap that width and height.

Comment: ભાઈ કયો ને Imageview ની Height અને width કેવી રીતે સેટ કરું

Comment: Bitmap bmpimg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,ph.getMeasuredWidth(), ph.getMeasuredWidth(), true);....... this is not work

Comment: You want the imageview to match your bitmap size or vice versa?

Comment: ya.. i want bitbap is fitt in imageview.

Answer (score 0):

will you can get `ImageView` size by imageViewObject.getWidth(); and obj.getHeight(); then scaled your bitmap following those value not tested.

```
Bitmap bmpimg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, obj.getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: this is not work....ViewTreeObserver vto = ph.getViewTreeObserver();
  vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
      public boolean onPreDraw() {
          ph.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
          ph.getMeasuredWidth();
          ph.getMeasuredWidth();
         
          return true;
      }
  });

Comment: haa!! what?! what is this.

Comment: i have found this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411975/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-view-in-android#

Comment: @user3855491 yes that getViewTreeObserver code is work and you can get width and Height from that.

Comment: you only need ImageView Height and Width, right, so you can't call getWidth() and getHeight() on ImageView from onCreate() in activity you have to wait for activity attached to window and then call getWidth() and getHeight(). just call getWidth() and getHeight() from anywhere else onCreate().

Comment: i want imageview height & width & aftre i'hve use this for set bitmap in imageview as size of imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very simple and easy solution am sure it will work for you
Use "scaleType" property of ImageView in your xml file 
keep it as  "scaleType=fitXY"
here is snippest

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Enjoy coding

Comment: sir, i want to set bitmap in imageview. but bitmap size must same as imageview size.

Comment: i know you just try this and second thing keep your bitmap ratio as per your requirement it will work just try this if it will not fulfill your requirement then reject this solution but first try this

Comment: you can change imageview height and width as per your requirment in XML

Comment: but brother my imageview size change as par mobile device. but bitmap is fix. so how can i adjust that??

Comment: ok
then you can set image view size in XML for all mobile and in java file you can calculate height and width of imageview progrmatically then set this height and width to bitmap during its formation and then set that bitmap to image view

Comment: i have set imageview size is WRAP CONTENT for all device showing in my update question. now how i do.??