# Measuring margin of a "fitCenter" imageView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, margins

Given a simple RelativeLayout like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0fffff">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img001" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

the left/top spacing between the layout border and the image border depends on the W/H ratio of the image being load in the imageView.

[image]

How can I know (programmatically) the real margin (width and height of the cyan area) after an image is shown in this layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method will calculate the **new rectangle which bounds the object after FIT_CENTER** and all **other related values.**

It should work on all cases of object and container.

[image]

```
 public static Rect calculateFitCenterObjectRect(float containerWidth, float containerHeight, float objectWidth, float objectHeight) {

        // scale value to make fit center
        double scale = Math.min( (double)containerWidth / (double)objectWidth, (double)containerHeight / (double)objectHeight);

        int h = (int) (scale * objectHeight); // new height of the object
        int w = (int) (scale * objectWidth); // new width of the object

        int x = (int) ((containerWidth - w) * 0.5f); // new x location of the object relative to the container
        int y = (int) ((containerHeight - h) * 0.5f); // new y  location of the object relative to the container

        return new Rect(x, y, x + w, y + h);
    }
```

You can use *FrameLayout* to position the view wherever you want after using the previous method with the new x, y, width, height of the scaled object.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the width of the `ImageView`, like this

```
int ivWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
```

and the total width of the layout (your `RelativeLayout`), like this

```
int layoutWidth = yourLayout.getWidth();
```

then, you can easily get the horizontal margin, like this

```
int horizontalMargin = (layoutWidth - ivWidth)/2;
```

And the same goes for height.

You should call functions like `getWidth` and `getHeight` after the dimensions of your layout have been calculated, as described by Veer's and Khan's answer on [How to get the width and height of an Image View in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411975/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-view-in-android#10412209).
Calling `getWidth` or `getHeight` in `onCreate` will return 0.