# Getting wrong values for android ImageView height and width

Tags: android, image

I have an ImageView with height and width as 360dp and 360dp.

But in my Java class if I try to get the height and width, it gives different values -

```
ImageView graph = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.graph);
    float he = graph.getMeasuredHeight();
    float wi = graph.getMeasuredWidth();
    Log.d("height of view", ""+he);
    Log.d("width of view", ""+wi);
```

the output is

```
height of view: 540
width of view: 480
```

What is the reason ? How should i get equal correct values ?

I'm using a Relative Layout.

Comment: `I have an ImageView with height and width as 360dp and 360dp` I see you still don't have clear the difference between **dp** and **px**...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks some minimal study about the typical Android measuring units.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411975/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-view-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your Imageview **`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`**
Finally,

```
<ImageView
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/"

/>
```

After that,you use `getWidth();` And `getHeight();` Method (PX Unit)

Answer (score 0):

Your imageview is fitting to your image ,you can set attribute

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```