# ImageView measured Height one time then removing Listener

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I don't understand why my ImageViewHeight is still 0 after having call "setBitmap", I need to put a marker at a precise place of the loaded picture so I have to know the size of it :

```
Picasso.with(iv.getContext())
    .load(AppConstants.SERVER_URL + "/api/" + question.getImage().getUrl())
    .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .into(new Target() {@Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        Log.i("renaud", "iv.getMeasuredHeight() : " + iv.getMeasuredHeight());
        Log.i("renaud", "iv.getMeasuredWidth() : " + iv.getMeasuredWidth());

    }

    ...

});
```

This log "0" for height and width.

the xml (iv correspond to "area_iv"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/area_relative"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="300dp"
        android:minHeight="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/area_iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answer_iv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

------------------- Thanks to you guys I did that :

```
Picasso.with(iv.getContext())
    .load(AppConstants.SERVER_URL + "/api/" + question.getImage().getUrl())
    .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .into(new Target() {@Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {@Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                Log.i("renaud", "iv.getMeasuredHeight() : " + iv.getMeasuredHeight());
                Log.i("renaud", "iv.getMeasuredWidth() : " + iv.getMeasuredWidth());
                iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }



});
```

Comment: before that line add `iv.onMeasure()` that mean before `Log`.

Comment: Plz add you layout contain imageview.

Comment: sorry for being late, I've been asked away from my computer.
I cant call iv.onMeasure, it's a protected attribute. I'm pasting my xml right now

Comment: use `ViewTreeObserver` and register for "global layout changes" (`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`)

Comment: Yes ViewTreeObserver is the right way to go. Your ImageView won't change layout right after you set it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the width and height of an Image View in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411975/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-view-in-android)

Comment: It's not conveignent to me as I don't want it to trigger eachtime my view change it's size.

Comment: so you want to know the new size or not?

Comment: So remove Observer right after you get dimensions of your ImageView

Comment: so the idea is 
iv.getViewTree..().setOnGlob..(new .. {
do my things..
iv.getViewTree..().removeGlobal(this)
}

?

Comment: oups it's awful in a comment

Comment: if you dont like `ViewTreeObserver` way, just use a custom `ImageView` and override its `onSizeChanged`, with custom `ImageView` you could also draw your marker inside `onDraw` method

Comment: ok it works thanks I update my answer

Comment: ok in fact I din't notice but the figures I have with Measure Height and Width are absurds.