# Center-crop an image into an ImageView with variable size?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a recycler view that has items with variable sizes. Now, I'm loading images using Picasso and I'd like to resize the pictures to fill the `ImageView`, preserving aspect ratio and by cropping the image so that it fits the `ImageView` perfectly. However, the width of the `ImageView` is 0 during the time the view holder is bound. How do I get the size?

The code looks something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    Foo foo = mFoos.get(position);

    // Get the size - THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO FIND OUT
    int width = ...;
    int height = 100;

    // Load the image using Picasso
    Picasso.with(mContext)
           .load(foo.getImageURL())
           .centerCrop()
           .resize(width, height)
           .into(holder.image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because view measurement has not jet been made. So at that point width is actually 0.
You need to implement [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html)

Take a look at some of these examples:

> [How to get the width and height of an Image View in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411975/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-view-in-android)
>
> [How to get the width and height of an android.widget.ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview)